# In remote Visual SVN Server Post Commit Cook is not working properly,

Tags: svn, post-commit-hook

In remote repo need to be auto updated but VISUAL SVN Server Post commit hook is not working Properly. This is my webhook code..
`PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin\"
set SVN_WORK_DIR=C:\Svn\Test"
svn update %SVN_WORK_DIR%`

It's returns below error:

Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 1) with output:
Error: svn: E155004: Run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
Error: svn: E155004: Failed to lock working copy 'C:\Svn\Test'.
Error: svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database
Error: svn: E200042: Additional errors:
Error: svn: E200031: sqlite[S8]: attempt to write a readonly database

I have try various code, but it's not working. Any one can help me????

Answer (score 0):

The error that you receive is most likely caused by lack of access permissions to `C:\Svn\Test`. You must provide the service account with Read/Write access to this directory.

The hook scripts run under the account that runs **VisualSVN Server** service. VisualSVN Server runs as Network Service account, by default.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did this, now working fine.